# In c# is it safe to expand a List that's being traversed with foreach?

Tags: c#, list, collections, foreach

In c# is it safe to expand a List that's being traversed with foreach?

Comment: `InvalidOperationException: Collection Was Modified`

Comment: It's usually best to think about it in Functional Programming terms - use LINQ to create a new list (or sequence) without modifying the old one.

Comment: You probably should have just tried it and saw you'd receive the exception @VirtualBlackFox gave you...  Anyway, there are a lot of ways to deal with scenarios where you would want to do this.  Maybe you need to subscribe to some change events, maybe you need to synchronize access, maybe a queue makes more sense...  What did you expect to happen when you added items?  You can probably still do that with a different approach...

Comment: It seems logically sound Pete M. The list is being traversed from start to end and sometimes during traversal elements are being added to the end.

Comment: Can you post more information about what you need to do?  We can probably provide some alternatives for you.

Comment: I think I've got it now, seems to work, see my answer below.

Comment: Side note: "safe" has very broad meaning. I.e. one can treat it as "will iteration be deterministic in case of underlying collection is modified?" - the answer would be yes - iteration will determinstically throw exception for all well-behaving collections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that by expand you mean to add new items to the collection. If so then the answer is not, you will get an exception on the traversal. I don't believe any collection can do this.

You can create a new list and then do an AddRange on the original list.

Answer (score 1):

> In c# is it safe to expand a List that's being traversed with foreach?  If not then how about other collections?

There are very few collections that safely let you add to them while being iterated.  There are quite a few options here - The most common would be to either build a new collection from the original, or add items into a temporary collection while iterating, then add them all to the original collection at the end.

The only collections in the framework which are designed with iteration and insertion in mind are some of the concurrent collections.  For example, you *can* be iterating a `BlockingCollection<T>` via [GetConsumingEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) and Add items to it at the same time.  However, this is intended for a different purpose - it's typically used when having a separate consumer and producer thread, one adding, while the other processes items.  As such, doing this within its own loop would be a very odd use case.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will get an exception. While it isn't recommended, you can accomplish what you're looking for by using a simple for loop. The reason you're getting an exception is because of how foreach works. When compiled it is actually using the `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable` that is implemented by the `List<T>` to get the items. Now you can create your own collection which would allow something like this, but again, not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

foreach is only for seeing values of any collection, if you'll be change number of elements in collection - exception will be thrown. If you will be change values in collection - nothing will happen, but Microsoft advice not to use foreach for such case.
IF you need to change elements or number of elements use list.ToArray() and FOR cycle through the array.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibly good, some complicated solutions here. How about cyling though the list with a while based on the lists length and the current position, that should work?

```
UInt16 n = 0;
while (n < list.Count)
{
    ... // might add new elements to the end of the list
    n++;
}
```

Comment: Just be wary of `List.Insert(int index, T)`

Comment: Also be aware that there is a race condition if somebody deletes an item from the list. If `n == list.Count - 1` and an item is removed, then trying to access `list[n]` will throw `IndexOutOfRangeExecption`.

Comment: I can see that there is a lot this can't do, it works well for this simple purpose though, having exactly the behaviour I'm after. I think the standard "foreach" should be more robust though, and also more consistant when used as in it's member function form as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a new list. For example with buttons:

```
List<Button> list = new List<Button>();
list.Add(new Button());
list.Add(new Button());

foreach (Button button in new List<Button>(list))
    list.Add(new Button());
```

Not the best solution, but probably the easiest.